# Why can't I `nice` a command group?

Tags: nice

```
[fakename]$ nice yes a>/dev/null &
[1] 26475
[fakename]$ ps -p 26475 -o nice,pid
 NI   PID
 10 26475
[fakename]$ nice { yes a>/dev/null; } &
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Is there a way to `nice` a command group?

I am aware of one: to execute the command group as normal, put it in the background by appending an ampersand, and use `renice` on the command group. However, is there a way to accomplish the same thing with `nice`?

Also, why exactly is it giving me this error? Is it because `nice` is not a shell keyword, and thus must follow standard bash argument parsing rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you like to use `nice` would require that `nice` is a reserved word in the shell but it is just a normal command that takes another simple command as an argument.

There is only on case where several shells did what you like to see. This is the `time` command that also exists as reserved word in some shells.

Answer (score 0):

The `nice` utility takes as its operand another *utility* (possibly with arguments).  It does not take a subshell or a compound command.

To run a compound command with `nice`, use a child shell:

```
nice sh -c 'mycommand; somethingelse; while [ something ]; do ...; done'
```

See also:

- [The POSIX documentation of `nice`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nice.html).
- `man nice` on your system.